# Java getter returning original value instead of value updated by setter

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm doing a project to make filters for a photo, where we set new RGB values with getter and setter methods.

```
public class Color {

private double red;
private double green;
private double blue;

public Color() {
this.setRed(1.0);
this.setGreen(1.0);
this.setBlue(1.0);
}

public Color(double red, double green, double blue) {
this.setRed(red);
this.setGreen(green);
this.setBlue(blue);
}

... (code for other functions after those tests pass)

public double getRed(){
  return red;
}

public void setRed(double color1){
  if (color1 <= 1.0){
      if (color1 >= 0.0){
          red = color1;
      }
  }
  else if (color1>1.0){
      red=1.0;
  }
  else if (color1<0.0){
      red=0.0;
  }
}

}
```

Each of the getters and setters are duplicates of getRed/setRed. I've checked the definitions via a program I do not have access to, but this is the output I have received:

Failed tests:

Scenario: 3.1 - after calling setRed(-1.0), getRed()'s return value should be 0.0

Color(1.0,1.0,1.0).setRed(-1.0) - OK

Color(1.0,1.0,1.0).getRed() - expected 0.0 - returned 1.0

So the setter is functioning as I need it to, but the getter is returning the original value. It's not an isolated case, each of my getters is returning the original value (1.0) for their respective colors while each setter successfully runs.

Comment: Are you creating a new Color every time you run the getter?

Comment: No new Color for each test run. We're using the same instance of Color for east test run of set/get

Comment: Single setter line: `this.red = color1 < 0.0 ? 0.0 : color1 > 1.0 ? 1.0 : color1;`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This seems to work to achieve the same endgoal but the instructor seems to have qualms with this implementation (at least the testing code does). Saving this as a note for future programs, though.

Comment: Just making some general recommendations: 1) since this is a value class, you should strongly consider making its instances *immutable*; 2) consider constructing color instances with the Builder Pattern; 3) the best place to test invariants on an immutable class is in the constructor (this would allow you to take the testing out of the setter methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last condition `else if (color1<0.0) { red=0.0; }` will never be `true`, because all cases when `color1` is less than `0` will be caught in first if statement `if (color1 <= 1.0)`. Hence, value `0.0` will never be set.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. Changing the nested if from plain if to if/else seems to have done the trick. Thanks much.

Comment: @jobosno Glad I could help. If this resolves your issue you can accept my answer by clicking on the mark on the oleft side of my response.

Comment: There seems to be a 15 minute minimum before you can accept answers. I'll be glad to mark it as such after said time limit expires. Thanks again!

Comment: @jobosno Ah, ok. Didn't know about that. Thanks.